# Facebook registration plug-in q's

Tags: facebook, plugins, ssl, https, registration

Does the registration plugin require my site to be https (SSL certified?). If that is not the case why does my registration plug-in have a blue bar that spins continuously? The page is at

```
sepserver.net/dsg/
```

Right now my return URI is sepserver.net/signedrequest.php as my site has no SSL cert self signed or otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer actually is that the registration plug-in will function without the need for SSL in some cases but for sure when all features of the fbxml registration plug-in are being used then SSL is required.